# How to parse XML for <![CDATA[]]>

Tags: java, xml, parsing, cdata

How to parse a XML having data included in `<![CDATA[---]...` how can we parse the xml and get the data included in `CDATA` ???

Comment: Do you parse the File "by hand" or use you any XMLReader Class (and which)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  File file = new File("data.xml");
  DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
 //if you are using this code for blackberry xml parsing
  builder.setCoalescing(true);
  Document doc = builder.parse(file);

  NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("topic");
  for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
    NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
    Element line = (Element) title.item(0);
    System.out.println("Title: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
  }
}
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
  Node child = e.getFirstChild();
  if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
    CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
    return cd.getData();
  }
  return "";
}
```

( http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/GetcharacterdataCDATAfromxmldocument.htm )

Comment: I would rather do something like :
if (child != null && (child instanceof CharacterData)) {
     return ((CharacterData) child).getData();
} else {
     return e.getNodeValue();
}
In order to handle seamlessly the presence/absence of CDATA block.

Comment: Can you please provide some text to describe what you are doing and why you would use the `DocumentBuilderFactory`?

Comment: In current Java DOM implementation you can access CDATA simply as text data  using `e.getTextContent()`. [See example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802202) without type check, cast, `e.getData()`.

Answer (score 4):

Since all previous answers are using a [DOM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html) based approach. This is how to parse CDATA with a stream based approach using [STAX](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/xml/stax.html).

Use the following pattern:

```
  switch (EventType) {
        case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
        case XMLStreamConstants.CDATA:
            System.out.println(r.getText());
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
```

Complete sample:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

public void readCDATAFromXMLUsingStax() {
    String yourSampleFile = "/path/toYour/sample/file.xml";
    XMLStreamReader r = null;
    try (InputStream in =
            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(yourSampleFile));) {
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        r = factory.createXMLStreamReader(in);
        while (r.hasNext()) {
            switch (r.getEventType()) {
            case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
            case XMLStreamConstants.CDATA:
                System.out.println(r.getText());
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            r.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (r != null) {
            try {
                r.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With /path/toYour/sample/file.xml

```
 <data>
    <![CDATA[ Sat Nov 19 18:50:15 2016 (1672822)]]>
    <![CDATA[Sat, 19 Nov 2016 18:50:14 -0800 (PST)]]>
 </data>
```

Gives:

```
 Sat Nov 19 18:50:15 2016 (1672822)                             
 Sat, 19 Nov 2016 18:50:14 -0800 (PST)
```

Answer (score 2):

`CDATA` just says that the included data should not be escaped. So, just take the tag text. XML parser should return the clear data without `CDATA`.

Comment: getting the text data: e.getTextContent();

Answer (score 0):

here `r.get().getResponseBody()` is the response body

```
Document doc = getDomElement(r.get().getResponseBody());            
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Title");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
    NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("Child tag where cdata present");
    Element line = (Element) title.item(0);
    System.out.println("Title: "+ getCharacterDataFromElement(line));


    public static Document getDomElement(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setCoalescing(true);
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doc;
    }

    public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
        Node child = e.getFirstChild();
        if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
            CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
            return cd.getData();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample XML file and the code to retrieve the XML embedded in the the CDATA within main xml.

```
<envelope>
 <Header>
  <id>123</id>
  <name>abc</name>
 </Header>
 <payload>
  <![CDATA[<?xml> <Document><validXML></validXML></Document>]]>
</payload>
</envelope>
```

Xpath to get the CDATA XML given in above example would be

```
/envelope/payload/text()
```

So, once you have the root Document of above xml, with the given Path you can fetch the xml embedded in the CDATA.

Below is the utility method for the same.

```
public String getSubDocument(Document rootDocument, String xPathString) throws Exception {
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document rootDoc = builder.newDocument();
String xmlString = (String)xPath.compile(xPathString).evaluate(rootDocument, XPathConstants.String);
return xmlString;
}
```

}