# dom4j - cant get cdata from xml

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I have question how can I get cdata from xml? So my xml looks like this:

```
<tag><![CDATA[Text]]></tag>
```

I tried to get word by getText(), getStringValue() but they return me empty string ;/
Any idea what should i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse XML for !\[CDATA\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489151/how-to-parse-xml-for-cdata)

Answer (score 0):

Hardly rocket science:

```
    System.out.println(DocumentHelper
            .parseText("<tag><![CDATA[Text]]></tag>").getRootElement()
            .getText());
```