# Parsing CDATA String as response from webservice

Tags: java, parsing, cdata

I have below string CDATA format from the response of a webservice call.

```
String outputString = "<![CDATA[<MYTAG><MYTAG1 type=\"java.util.vector\"><MyTAG2    type=\"java.util.hashtable\"><NAME type=\"java.lang.string\">XYZ</NAME><ADDRESS type=\"java.lang.string\">ABCD</ADDRESS></MYTAG2></MYTAG1></MYTAG>]]>"
```

When i tried with DOM parser. This string is giving exception.

```
DocumentBuilder builder;
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document outputXMLDocument = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(outputString)));
NodeList nodes = outputXMLDocument.getElementsByTagName("MYTAG");
```

I want to parse this respone and retrieve the value of NAME and ADDRESS TAG. Please advice for best way to handle this.

Comment: Please check this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489151/how-to-parse-xml-for-cdata It might help.

Comment: That CDATA value must have come out of an XML file as the text valud of an enclosing node.  When you were parsing the containing XML you would have a text node.  Fire up another `DocumentBuilder` and feed it the string value extracted from the text node.  At that point it won't be a CDATA section since CDATA is present only in the serialized version of the document, never in the DOM.

Comment: In response of webservice call.. I don't have any node preceeding to CDATA. Ratiher it just have string as i mentioned String     outputString = "<![CDATA[<MYTAG><MYTAG1 type=\"java.util.vector\"><MyTAG2    type=\"java.util.hashtable\"><NAME type=\"java.lang.string\">XYZ</NAME><ADDRESS type=\"java.lang.string\">ABCD</ADDRESS></MYTAG2></MYTAG1></MYTAG>]]>"

Answer (score 0):

The data inside `CDATA` will not be parsed by the parser. The section inside CDATA is intended to have data that can't be sent in a `XML`. Say if you have `<` and `&` in XML, they have their own special meaning. These type of content are placed in `CDATA` section

The below snippet can help you parse the character data from the element.

```
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
  Node child = e.getFirstChild();
  if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
    CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
      System.out.println(cd.getData());
    return cd.getData();
  }
  return "";
}
```

You can create a document with the response you get from webservice and then perform the parsing, if just CDATA is available.

Hope it helps!

Comment: In fact it doesn't. Returned data is still wrapped in CDATA