# JAVA how to find and delete the structure of sentences?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have a xml file, and its structure is like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="MS949"?> 
 <pmd-cpd>
    <duplication lines="123" tokens"123"> 
        <file line="1" path="..">
        <file line="1" path="..">
        <codefragment><![CDATA[........]]></codefragment>
    </duplication>
    <duplication>
    ...
    </duplication>
 </pmd-cpd>
```

I want to delete 'codefragment' node, because my parser make an error 'invalid XML character(0x1). '

My parsing code is like this,

```
private void parseXML(File f){
      DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder builder = null;
      Document document = null;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        document = builder.parse(f);
     }catch(...)
```

The error happens in `document = builder.parse(f);` so I cannot use parser to delete the `codefragment` node.

This is why I want to delete these lines without the parser.

How can I delete this node without the parser...?

Comment: have you try this ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489151/how-to-parse-xml-for-cdata

Comment: thanks but that does not fit to my problem.. to use that I should parse my file but in my case I cant even parse my file because of the invaild character

Comment: then it's not valid XML. try to use a regex before to delete [CDATA ...] . Not totally safe

Comment: If the XML file contains bad characters, you should fix whatever program created the file. Valid character data is defined by the [XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Char) to be `#x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]`, which means that `#x1` (aka `0x1`) is **not** valid.

Comment: It seems to be more of an encoding problem.  The character that is causing the problem is not supported by the encoding="MS949".  You could try a different encoding such as encoding="UTF-8"

Comment: @MikeMurphy `0x1` *is* defined by MS949. It is however not allowed by XML.

Comment: @MikeMurphy I'm sorry to late reply, but I could solve the problem. How I can solve was to delete the wrong characters and then parse that.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, my xml file had bad characters but I could not the program which created that file, because it's not my program and even do not have the source.(that was PMD, static analyzer)  Thank you for your help..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a followup answer to OP's self-answer, and the comment I made to that answer. Here's the recap, plus some extra:

- Never do `String += String` in a loop. Use `StringBuilder`.
- Read the XML in blocks, not lines.
- Don't use `String.replaceAll()`. It has to recompile the regex every time, a regex you already have. Use `Matcher.replaceAll()`.
- Remember to `close()` the Reader. Better yet, use `try-with-resources`.
- No need to save the clean XML back out, just use it directly.
- Since XML is *usually* in UTF-8, read the file as UTF-8.
- Don't print and ignore errors. Let caller handle errors.

```java
private static void parseXML(File f) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f),
                                                                      StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        Pattern badChars = Pattern.compile("[^\\u0009\\u000a\\u000d\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD]+");
        char[] cbuf = new char[1024];
        for (int len; (len = in.read(cbuf)) != -1; )
            xml.append(badChars.matcher(CharBuffer.wrap(cbuf, 0, len)).replaceAll(""));
    }
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = domBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml.toString())));
    // insert code using DOM here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this problem was, to remove the bad characters such as x01, save as new XML file, and then parse the new file.

Because I could not even parse my old xml file, I could not remove the node with parser.

So removing invalid character and saving as a new file code was like this.

```
//save the xml string as a new file.
public static Document stringToDom(String xmlSource) 
        throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));
}

//get the file and remove bad characters in it
private static void cleanString(File fileName) {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String xmlLines, cleanXMLString="";
        Pattern p = null;
        Matcher m = null;

        p = Pattern.compile("[^\\u0009\\u000a\\u000d\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD]");
        while (((xmlLines = in.readLine()) != null)){
            m = p.matcher(xmlLines);
            if (m.find()){
                cleanXMLString = cleanXMLString + xmlLines.replaceAll("[^\\u0009\\u000a\\u000d\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD]", "")+"\n";
            }else
                cleanXMLString = cleanXMLString + xmlLines+"\n";
        }

        Document doc = stringToDom(cleanXMLString);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(new File("\\new\\"+fileName.getName()));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (IOException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Maybe, that's not good method since it takes quite long time for even a small file(under 5MB).

But if your file is small, you can try this...

Comment: Never do `String += String` in a loop. Use `cleanXml = new StringBuilder()`. It's faster. --- Since you don't care about lines, read in blocks, as in `readLen = in.read(cbuf)`. It's faster. --- Don't use that `replaceAll()`. It has to recompile the regex every time, a regex you already have. Just use `cleanXml.append(p.matcher(new String(cbuf, 0, readLen)).replaceAll(""))`. It's faster. --- Remember to `in.close()` the reader. Better yet, use try-with-resources. --- No need to DOM load the XML. Just use a `StreamSource` from the String.